# How can I see in telegram bot incoming POST request from Java web app

Tags: java, bots, telegram

I have a web application.

I'm sending some photo to telegram bot using:

```
https://api.telegram.org/<token>/sendPhoto.
```

By executing this command from my web app, bot receiving image.

How can I make bot react on this incoming events?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can only use query strings with the availed methods to send messages/photos from a bot to a specified user i.e

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<id>&text=<string>
```

Hitting the endpoint below opens your bot in the telegram web app which is not helpful in your situation

```
https://telegram.me/<botNname>?start
```

Bottom line is that you cannot send updates to a bot using a URL,